# How to "observe" changes to `localStorage` in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that is going to work with along with a web application.

As part of one of the features, we'd like to authenticate a user in the extension, if the user authenticates in the web application.

My initial idea to accomplish this was to create a content script in the extension that only runs when the user is on the web application:

```
  "matches": [
    "*://login.mywebapp.com/*"
  ],
  "js": ["/localStorageTransfer.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
```

And that content script will essentially copy the contents of `localStorage['_u']` to the sync storage in Chrome.

That approach works fine when the user is already logged in. However, the main problem that I'm trying to solve right now is when the user is **not** logged in.

My web application is a SPA, so initially I thought I could listen the `storage` event on the window object to detect `storage` changes, but the event for some reason is not firing, this is the code that I'm using to detect that:

```
// localStorageTransfer.js
window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => {
  console.dir(e); // this never fires after logging a user in.
});
```

The alternative approach that I tried was using Proxies to "observe" `localStorage` this approach doesn't seem to be working, and to be fair I'm not even sure if the code below actually works:

```
// localStorageTransfer.js
let proxiedStorage = new Proxy(localStorage, {
  set: (target, prop, value) => {
    console.log({type: 'set', target, prop, value});
    return Reflect.set({target, prop, value});
  }
});
```

In summary, what I'm trying to accomplish is to authenticate a user in my chrome extension if that user authenticates (or is already authenticated) in a web app.

Comment: Since the content scripts run in "isolated world", you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: @wOxxOm that's exactly what I'm doing, but I'm running intoa problem described in the body of the question.

Comment: Does the page use proxiedStorage? Generally, I would expect you to assign it to `window.localStorage`

Comment: no, the page doens't use `proxiedStorage`

Comment: Well then your proxy isn't actually used.

Comment: I see what you're saying @wOxxOm the `proxy` doesn't really "listen" to changes in localStorage, it listens on the proxied object, so a `Proxy` is more like an `Object.assign` plus Observer pattern on the target object?